# Почему этот код работает? HeapAlloc

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь научится выделять динамически память с помощью winapi.

```
{
HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
TCHAR *strName = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, 1 * sizeof(TCHAR));
lstrcpy(strName, _T("Hello"));
MessageBox(0, strName, 0, 0);
HeapFree(hHeap, 0, strName);
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, почему этот код нормально работает.. Вроде как я выделяю память под 1 символ, а заношу туда 5 символов(это не включая завершающего нуля), более того, даже если я вместо 1 * sizeof(TCHAR) напишу 0, оно тоже работает и выдает полноценное Hello. Объясните, как это работает? Есть ли другие, не касающиеся темы, косяки в данном коде? Спасибо.

Comment: Вопроса "почему этот код *работает*" в мире С и С++ не существует. Компилируемый, но ошибочный, код порождает *неопределенное поведение*. Которое до поры до времени может проявлять себя внешне как якобы "работающий" код. Именно это вы и наблюдаете.

Answer (score 3):

HeapAlloc выделяет и возвращает указатель на блок памяти размером в 1 TCHAR. Но физическая память (или даже виртуальная) на этом не заканчивается. Ваш lstrcpy использует ее, но "без спроса". Скорее всего, там ничего важного не оказалось и поэтому программа "работает". Если выделить еще один блок памяти сразу после первого, то возможно, что lstrcpy его перезапишет и тогда код, использующий этот второй блок скорее всего будет работать неправильно, разве что только если вы не полагались на эту перезапись. Хотя, что такое "неправильно" - это очень большой вопрос! :)

Возможно, еще дело в том, что HeapAlloc выделяет блок *достаточного* размера, а скорее всего, большего.

Comment: Ничего перетираться скорее всего не будет. Если я правильно помню, то минимально выделяется от 6 байт (а этого хватит на Hello\0. А может и больше - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120316-00/?p=8083